# Obtaining incorrect data using class object in different class

Tags: c++

hey guys im writing a loan program here using two classes. I declare an object from my "MortCalc" Class in My LoanOfficer Class. The loan officer class is to determine whether a user qualifies for a loan or not a user enters the principal of a loan, monthly income, and monthly expenses. The Loan officer class then does a calculation and reports back to the user if the loan was approved using one rule. The rule is this: if the monthly payment of the loan( which is obtained from my MortCalc Class) and monthly expenses total is greater than 50% of the monthly income then the loan is not approved. The problem I've encountered is with calculating this. I try to store the calculation in a "rule" variable but it always equals 100 thus never approving the loan! obviously im doing something wrong here but i can't figure out what. here is my code:

**LoanOfficer.h**

```
class LoanOfficer
{
//private class variables
private:
MortCalc mc;
double intRate;
double monthlyIncome;
double term;
double monExpenses, principal;
double rule;
bool bLoanApprove, bOpen;
string userName, fileName,lenderName;
string loanOfficer, Welcome;
int counter;
void calculate();
```

**LoanOfficer.cpp**

```
LoanOfficer::LoanOfficer()
{
//initializing variables;
intRate = 4.1;
term = 30;
counter=1;
principal=0;
lenderName="John's Bank";
Welcome ="";
calculate();
}
void LoanOfficer::calculate()
{

rule = ((mc.GetMonPymt() + monExpenses) / monthlyIncome)* 100;
    //i have a getter in my Mortcalc class which get's the monthly Payment.

}
bool LoanOfficer::isApproved()
{
if(rule>50)
{
    bLoanApprove = true;
}
else{
    bLoanApprove = false;
}
return bLoanApprove;
}
string LoanOfficer::getApproval()
 {
if(bLoanApprove==true)
{
  stringstream ss;
        ss<<"\n\nLoan Approval Status: Yes"
        <<"\nLoan amount: "
        <<principal
        <<"\nInterest Rate: "
        <<intRate
        <<"\nMonthly Payment: "
        <<monPayment
        <<"\nTotalLoan: "
        <<mc.GetTotalLoan()
        <<"\nTotal Interest"
        <<mc.GetTotalInt()
        <<"\n\nCongratulations We're looking to do business with you "
        <<userName<<"!";
    loanOfficer = ss.str();
}
else
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<"\n\nLoan Approval Status: No"
       <<"\n\n  Income vs Montly Payment and expenses does not meet "
       <<"\n  the 50% criteria net income that is necessary for this"
       <<"\n  institution to approve this loan";
    loanOfficer = ss.str();
}

return loanOfficer;
}
void LoanOfficer::setPrincipal(double p)
{
mc.setPrin(p);
principal = p;
}
bool LoanOfficer::isOpen()
{
return bOpen;
}
void LoanOfficer::setMonInc(double mi)
{
monthlyIncome = mi;
}
void LoanOfficer::setExpenses(double ex)
{
monExpenses = ex;
}

void LoanOfficer::setAppName(string n)
{
userName = n;
 }
string LoanOfficer::getFilename()
{
return fileName;
}
string LoanOfficer::getIntro()
{
stringstream ss;
    ss<<"Hi Welcome to " <<lenderName
    <<"\n Please enter your information below to see if you're approved for a loan."
    <<"\nWe have a fixed interest rate of 4.1 and term of loan is 30 years."
            <<"\nThe way we determine our loan approvals is by adding 
                loan payment and monthly expenses,"
            <<"\nand that is greater than 50% of your monthly income the loan 
                is notapproved.\n\n";
    Welcome = ss.str();
return Welcome;
}

void LoanOfficer::writeStatus()
{

stringstream ss;

    ss<<userName<<"_"<<counter<<".txt";
    fileName = ss.str();

    ofstream receiptOut;
    receiptOut.open(fileName.c_str());

//Writing report setting precision to 2 decimal places
//returning true if able to write receipt.
    receiptOut<<" CUSTOMER LOAN INFORMATION " 
        <<month+1<<"/"<<day<<"/"<<year+1900<<"\n\n"
        <<"********************************"
        <<"\n Your Loan Information: "
        << "\n\n Principal: "<<"$" << fixed << setprecision (2) 
        << principal
        << "\n\n Interest rate: "<< fixed << setprecision (2) 
        << intRate << "%"
        << "\n\n Monthly Payment: "<<"$" << fixed << setprecision (2) 
        << mc.GetMonPymt()
                    //here it obtains the correct monthly payment. I've checked through
                    //debugging.

        << "\n\n Total Interest paid: " <<"$"<< fixed << setprecision (2) 
        << mc.GetTotalInt()
        <<"\n\n Total Cost of the Loan: "<<"$" << fixed << setprecision (2) 
        << mc.GetTotalLoan()
        <<"\n*********************************"
        <<"\n\n\nThank You for using my calculator. Have a Nice Day."
        <<"\n****************************************************";
        receiptOut.close();
        counter++;
        }
```

**main.cpp**

```
double principal,monthlyIncome,monthlyExpenses;
string name, answer;
string fAnswer
//class object
LoanOfficer lo;

cout<<lo.getIntro();

cout<<"Please enter your name: ";
cin>>name;

//passing name to setName class method.
lo.setAppName(name);


//start of do loop
do
{
    //presenting the user a menu accessed from otherFunctions.cpp
    //checking which choice user entered with switch statements
      cout<<"\nPlease enter the amount you want to borrow: ";
       cin>>principal;
       cin.ignore();
       lo.setPrincipal(principal);
    cout<<"\nPlease enter your monthly income after taxes: ";
        cin>>monthlyIncome;
        cin.ignore();
        lo.setMonInc(monthlyIncome);
    cout<<"\nPlease enter your monthly expenses: ";
        cin>>monthlyExpenses;
        cin.ignore();
        lo.setExpenses(monthlyExpenses);
  cout<<lo.getApproval();

cout<<"\n\n Would you like to write a file? Enter y for yes and n for no\n";
        cin>>fAnswer;
        if(fAnswer =="y")
        {
            lo.writeStatus();
            cout<<"\n\nReport is located in: "
                <<lo.getFilename();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\n\nNo report printed out.";
        }
    //ask if user would like to do another
cout<<"\n\nWould you like to do another loan? Enter y for yes and n for no\n";
    cin>>answer;
    cout<<"\n";
}while(answer =="y");
//end do/while

//Goodbye message
    {
    cout <<"\n Thanks for calculating. Goodbye!\n\n"; //when loop is done
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Formatting your code correctly makes it easier to read. Also, `string` w/o its pal `std::` in a header = no-no.

Comment: even when `using namespace std;`? @C.Lang

Comment: @JohnAcosta `using` declarations in headers are evil and have all kinds of weird consequences. Try declaring a class `count` after including `algorithm` and a `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I've never taken much thought into that @C.Lang I'm in a c++ II course currently and we always just declare it in a header as `string`

Comment: @JohnAcosta: change `*100` to anything else and see if you get that.

Comment: yes `rule` is whatever the last number is. so i changed it to `*50` and `rule` is now 50.000000000000000.

Comment: That's what I thought. So you know where the problem lies, it's in your data. If you hard coded the numbers you think are there the program would likely work the way you're intending.

Answer (score 0):

Change *business logic!*
You **idea contradicts to your realization**.
Let`s look closer at this statement in you question:
"The rule is this: if the monthly payment of the loan( which is obtained from my MortCalc Class) and monthly expenses total is greater than 50% of the monthly income then the loan is not approved. " and find place in your code where this business logic is implemented, here it is:

```
bool LoanOfficer::isApproved()
{
if(rule>50)
{
    bLoanApprove = true;
}
else{
    bLoanApprove = false;
}
```

from the code extract one can easily find that it contradicts your business logic.
**Solution:**

```
bool LoanOfficer::isApproved()
    {
    if(rule>50)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: right! but my rule variable is still not doing the correct calculation. for example if i were to enter 1000 for the principal, 8000 for monthly income and 200 for expenses. Monthly payment for the loan would be 4.83 for that loan (which is done in my mortcalc class with a 4.1 fixed interest rate and a 30 year term.) so it would be 4.83 + 200 / 8000 * 100 which equals 2.560375 so obviously the bool should return true but it doesn't because it's not calculating correctly.rule is coming out to 100.00000000000000!!! @spin_eight

Comment: @JohnAcosta: have you watched it with a debugger to see when/where it goes wrong?

Comment: @C.Lang yes i am using the debugger. all the right values are stored in their proper variables when i enter those numbers.  mc.GetMonPymt() is: 4.8319837110249075; monExpenses is:200.00000000000000; monthlyIncome is: 8000.0000000000000, and for some reason rule value is: 100.00000000000000.

Comment: @C.Lang it pays no attention to the calculation. Why? where is it getting 100.00000000000000 from?

Comment: @C.Lang The value in rule should be 2.56039979638781134375.